# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to run a utility class which calls some project specific classes, from .bat file. Utility class runs fine from Eclipse IDE but from command line I get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Interceptor`.
 I assumed that to fix this issue I should find corresponding jar from the project's lib folder and set it explicitly into the bat file's CLASSPATH. But I could not find any jar with class org.hibernate.Interceptor.
 What is wrong with my approach? I have following hibernate related jars in my lib folder:

- hibernate3.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

Batch file has just two commands

```
@ECHO OFF
java -cp .;D:\Projects\Name\webapps\WEB-INF\classes dbchanges.CreateQuery
```

Comment: Can you please share your .bat file's relevant statements?

Comment: Do you have everything necessary on your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I have to include all the necessary jars into CLASSPATH.

Sorry for stupid question :(